# Unable to access PHP site in subdirectories using IIS7

Tags: php, iis-7

I have IIS7 running locally on my machine, and I've installed PHP 5.6. I placed a file, `phpinfo.php`, in `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\phpinfo.php` which simply contains the script `<?php @phpinfo(); ?>`.

If I navigate to `localhost/phpinfo.php` I get the desired output.

I'm trying to install [phpBB](http://phpBB.com). I've downloaded the files and extracted them here: `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\phpBB3\`.

The install doc starts off with:

> Once all the files have been uploaded to your site, you should point your browser at this location with the addition of /install/. For example, if your domain name is www.example.com and you placed the phpBB files in the directory /phpBB3 off your web root you would enter http://www.example.com/phpBB3/install/ or (alternatively) http://www.example.com/phpBB3/install/index.php into your browser. When you have done this, you should see the phpBB Introduction screen appear.

However, if I navigate to `localhost/phpBB3/install` or `localhost/phpBB3/install/index.php` I'm presented with this error:

> HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
>   The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
>
> Error Code    0x8007000d
>
> Requested URL http://localhost:80/phpBB3/install/index.php
>
> Physical Path C:\inetpub\wwwroot\phpBB3\install\index.php

I've confirmed the file exists:

[image]

The only SO post I could find of value is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/190877/1189566 and the forum linked in the answer is blocked by my work's web filters, naturally.

I've never had to install PHP before, so I'm sure I'm just doing something dumb with my config files but I don't know what.

These are the values I changed:
`fastcgi.impersonate = 1`, `cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0`, `cgi.force_redirect = 0`, `open_basedir = C:\inetpub\wwwroot\`, `extension_dir = "./ext"`, and I found a recommendation to comment out the `doc_root` setting on the Microsoft forums. That did not make a difference.

Any ideas as to why I can execute PHP scripts in `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\` but no subdirectories?

Edit;

I found this link: https://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/using-fastcgi-to-host-php-applications-on-iis

And that's pretty much what I did the first time. It also suggests I create that script which just calls `phpinfo()`, which is successful. However, it then says

> NOTE: If you do not see FastCgiModule in the Modules: list, the module is either not registered or not enabled.

But this is all I see, assuming I'm looking at the right section:

[image]

The IIS config file it mentions next located at `%windir%\windows\system32\config\applicationHost.config` does not exist for me.

Comment: It looks like some users received this error due to the configuration requiring URL rewrite which you may need to install:  https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Comment: Did you check/install URL Rewrite to see if that's the issue?  Here's the forum post that calls out the dependency, even though it's not clear in the documentation: https://www.phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?f=466&t=2316061&start=15

Comment: Just left the office, I'll try that tomorrow @vanlee1987

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into the NTFS permissions on other directories? I've had the exact same issue before with ASP and it would only allow me to run scripts in the `wwwroot`.

I tried to find the same reference which helped me but found this link instead which is even better:

https://forums.iis.net/t/1200871.aspx?+php+file+on+folder+under+wwwroot+refuses+to+run

Comment: I gave `Full Control` to everyone on the `phpBB3` folder, just to make sure  -- no difference.

Comment: Did you propagate this to ALL subfolders and files within phpBB3?

Comment: Does the phpinfo() work in other subfolders nested in phpBB3...maybe worth just doing a spot check to test.

Comment: By default permissions are inherited from parent directories, so yes.

Comment: Also, ApplicationHost.config for II7 is here now: `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config`

Comment: Thanks; I've left the office for now but I'll try that tomorrow morning.

Comment: It works if I place it in `wwwroot\phpTest\phpinfo.php` but if I move it into `www\phpBB3\`` or any of the subdirectories there I cannot access `phpinfo.php` -- get the error in my original question. Going to try getting the network guys to install that URL Rewrite extension / try what your link suggests

Comment: Cheers for the update and let us know how you get on.